# How to Deny Permission to sub-user to edit only one field and only admin has control to access it...?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

Here is My Django Model

```
type_choices = [
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('no', 'no'),
    ]

verified= models.CharField(max_length=50,default='----',choices=type_choices)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                       default='',
                                       validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])
age= models.TextField(max_length=5000,
                                       default='')
```

I have a record called Verified and I have to Deny Permission to use the record to all Users and this record should only be used by Admins.

Can you help me how to restrict other users to change this record and only readable and admin should have the privilege to change the values of the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) on your ModelAdmin, you can dynamically return the list of fields for each request

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = MyModel

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = ['name', 'age']
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fields.append('verified')
        return fields
```

Comment: I got an Error "get_fields() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: Ah sorry I messed up the method definition, fixed

Comment: again, I gets an error "'bool' object is not callable"